# How to order files in a list.

Tags: r

I have a list with some elements.

```
 $y
  [1] "/data/y_11_au_fg.txt"
  [2] "/data/y_11_sp_fg.txt"
  [3] "/data/y_11_su_fg.txt"
  [4] "/data/y_11_wi_fg.txt"
  [5] "/data/y_12_au_fg.txt"
  [6] "/data/y_12_sp_fg.txt"
  [7] "/data/y_12_su_fg.txt"
  [8] "/data/y_12_wi_fg.txt"
```

The files are ordered based on the number`11 and 12` which is good but I need also specific order I need first `au then wi then sp then su`

Final output wanted:

```
  $y
    [1] "/data/y_11_au_fg.txt"
    [2] "/data/y_11_wi_fg.txt"
    [3] "/data/y_11_sp_fg.txt"
    [4] "/data/y_11_su_fg.txt"
    [5] "/data/y_12_au_fg.txt"
    [6] "/data/y_12_wi_fg.txt"
    [7] "/data/y_12_sp_fg.txt"
    [8] "/data/y_12_su_fg.txt"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a custom `order`, we loop through the `list` elements (`lapply(lst, ..`), extract the numeric part with `gsub`, convert to `numeric` ('v1'), similarly extract only the substring part that have 'au/wi/sp/su' ('v2'), convert that to `factor` class with `levels` specified in the order described in the OP's post, then we `order` the vectors 'v1', 'v3' and use that numeric index to order the original vector ('x').

```
 lapply(lst, function(x) {v1 <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", x))
                           v2 <- gsub(".*\\d+_|_.*", "", x)
                           v3 <- factor(v2, levels = c("au", "wi", "sp", "su"))

                           x[order(v1, v3)]
                           })
#$y
#[1] "/data/y_11_au_fg.txt"
#[2] "/data/y_11_wi_fg.txt"
#[3] "/data/y_11_sp_fg.txt"
#[4] "/data/y_11_su_fg.txt"
#[5] "/data/y_12_au_fg.txt" 
#[6] "/data/y_12_wi_fg.txt"
#[7]  "/data/y_12_sp_fg.txt"
#[8] "/data/y_12_su_fg.txt"
```

#### data

```
lst <- structure(list(y = c("/data/y_11_au_fg.txt", "/data/y_11_sp_fg.txt", 
 "/data/y_11_su_fg.txt", "/data/y_11_wi_fg.txt", "/data/y_12_au_fg.txt", 
"/data/y_12_sp_fg.txt", "/data/y_12_su_fg.txt", "/data/y_12_wi_fg.txt"
)), .Names = "y")
```